# Pass simple objects and a collection to MVC3 controller - what is proper use of traditional?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to get the syntax right for this AJAX request. I know that I need to use the 'traditional: true' parameter for my list, but it breaks the other parameters being passed:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '../Workflow/GetTasks',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: {
        queueID: filterData.queueID,
        workflowFilterID: filterData.workflowFilterID,
        genericFilters: filterData.genericFilters
    },
    traditional: true,
    success: function (data) {
    },
    error: function (error) {
        window.console && console.error(error);
    }
});
```

My controller's GetTasks method:

```
public ActionResult GetTasks(TaskFilter taskFilter)

public class TaskFilter
{
    public int QueueID { get; set; }
    public int WorkflowFilterID { get; set; }
    public List<GenericFilter> GenericFilters { get; set; }
}

public class GenericFilter
{
    public int AttributeID { get; set; }
    public string FirstValue { get; set; }
    public string SecondValue { get; set; }
}
```

I can successfully get my queueID and `workflowFilterID`. Depending on my settings, I either get null for `GenericFilters`, an empty list, or a list with 2 items in it but none of the items properties are set.

Currently, passing `traditional: true` results in `queueID` and `workflowFilterID` being defined, but `genericFilters` is a list with 0 items in it. I receive a list with 2 empty objects if I comment out the traditional paramater.

Could someone help me with the syntax for this? I've tried wrapping `genericFilters` in `$.param(filterData.genericFilters, true)`. I've tried `JSON.stringify()` on the entire object..

Comment: How about if you JSON.stringify your data and use a POST instead of a GET? Could you also show the URL requested by your GET request?

Comment: I would try stringify the filterData object and pass it on directly

Comment: What does your filterData.genericFilters look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things I wonder about, but most of all, complex objects like Lists should be posted.

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
```

Comment: So it was a combination of passing POST instead of GET in addition to calling JSON.stringify() on the entire object being passed as data.